# How to set Info.Plist to get AWSS3TransferManager.default work

Tags: swift

I'm getting an error while I'm trying to get default from AWSS3TransferManager. It says

'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The service configuration is `nil`. You need to configure `Info.plist` or set `defaultServiceConfiguration` before using this method.'

here is my code

```
func downloadFromS3() {

    var downloadCount = 0
    for index in 0...2 {
        let  downloadingFilePath = NSTemporaryDirectory().appendingFormat("banner%d.jpg", index+1)
        let downloadingFileURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: downloadingFilePath)

        let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()
        let downloadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest()

        downloadRequest?.bucket = BPAWSBannerBucketName
        downloadRequest?.key = String(format: "banner%d.jpg",index+1)
        downloadRequest?.downloadingFileURL = downloadingFileURL

        print("started download process")

        let task = transferManager.download(downloadRequest!)
        task.continueWith (block: {
            (task) -> AnyObject! in

            if task.error != nil {
                print("Error: \(String(describing: task.error))")
            } else {
                print("Download successful")

                let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: downloadingFilePath)
                self.bannerImageArr?.add(image!)
                downloadCount += 1
                if downloadCount == 3 {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.bannerCollectionView.reloadData()

                    }
                }
            }
            return nil
        }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the defaultServiceConfiguration in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` application delegate method.

```swift
let credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1, identityPoolId: "YourIdentityPoolId")
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)
AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

Comment: how to get identityPoolId? and any changes in info.plist to add poolId?

Comment: I already used this but i used access key .here is my code
 let credentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey:BPAWSAccessKey, secretKey: BPAWSSecretKey)
        let defaultServiceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
        //        defaultServiceConfiguration.maxRetryCount = 5
        AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = defaultServiceConfiguration